# How to force Skype for Business to accept all certificates?

Tags: certificate, skype-for-business

I am getting this error when I am trying to log in to Skype For Business from my home PC.

[image]

Event Viewer says "The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate."

I tried to extract the certificate from Event Log and store it in my Certificate Store but the error still persists.

How can I force Skype for business to accept all certificates? I know this is not the correct way. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: "How can I force Skype for business to accept all certificates?" - You can't, which is a good thing, but you can trust the certificate and Skype will connect. If its not connecting then you have missed something.  Did you trust all certificates involved?

Comment: I extracted certificate from Event Log and put it in my Certificate Store in Trusted Root. Still the error persists. Any way I can get the certificate which  this is complaining about? Fiddler captures nothing.

Comment: Don't put the extracted certificate into the Trusted Root, but the root certificate of its CA chain.